If $k_1(p)<0<k_2(p)$, then, there exists $v\in\ T_pS-\{\vec0\} $ with $II_p(v,v)=0$
where :
$k_i(p)$ are the principal curvatures
$T_pS$ is the tangent space
and $II_p$ is the second fundamental form
my approach :
we find a specific one
$v\in\ T_pS-\{\vec0\} \implies v=ae_1(p)+be_2(p)$ for $\{e_1,e_2\}$ some orthnormal basis of $T_pS$
$\implies\ II_p(v,v)=a^2k_1(p)+b^2k_2(p)=0$ if.f. $b=+-\sqrt\frac{-a^2k_1(p)}{k_2(p)}$ (definable fraction, positive quantity under the root)
and this supposedly does the job. however i'm having trouble during the verification process. anyone care to clarify? is my thinking correct, is this the form in which the final solution must be formatted in or do i need to go about it in terms of proof existence rather than calculation of one? i'm just now getting into differential geometry so don't come for me please kay thanks

Are you familiar with Euler's formula $\kappa = k_1 \cos^2\theta + k_2 \sin^2 \theta$? That will make things easier.

i am, i was thinking of using it but i thought it wasn't necessary. if i am wrong, could you explain where that is?

Hint: If we had $k_1=-k_2$, the angle $\theta = \pi/4$ would do the trick. How can you adjust this if they're different? The angle will depend on the ratio of the principal curvatures.

This is fine, although I personally would write it as $b=\pm a\sqrt{-k_1/k_2}$.
